# How to correctly format instance variables on a Rails model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have one table Materials, which `has_one` relation to MaterialCosts and `has_one` relation to MaterialCharges. They both belong to Material and should `dependent: :destroy` upon deletion or record in Material.

I am not sure about how to structure the Material class. Two attributes from each instance of Material must be used to calculate fields in MaterialCosts and MaterialCharges. These are `cost_per_sqm` and `ink_per_sqm`. `factor` is a field from Material which is also used for MaterialCharges. Do I need to initialize them in Material, in order to use the instance variables for the create methods? Or is the `attr_accessor` all that is required?

I know the code needs refactoring, but I am getting this error also when I try to seed data:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass on line 26 seeds.rb
```

lines 26 seeds.rb :

`Material.create({ 
product_name: "Novajet Art 255gsm", guk_name: "none", roll_width_in: 44, roll_length_m: 30, factor: 7, rounded_sale_price: 71, list_price: 240.00, cost_per_sqm: 7.16, ink_per_sqm: 3, supplier_discount: 0, sell_per_sqm: 71.11 
})`

This is my code:

```
  class Material < ApplicationRecord

  has_and_belongs_to_many :job_entries
  has_one :material_cost,  dependent: :destroy
  has_one :material_charge, dependent:  :destroy

  attr_accessor :cost_per_sqm, :ink_per_sqm, :factor

  def initialize(options)
    @cost_per_sqm = options['cost_per_sqm'].to_f
    @ink_per_sqm = options['ink_per_sqm'].to_f
    @factor = options['@factor'].to_f
    @total_cost = @cost_per_sqm * @ink_per_sqm
  end


  after_create :set_material_cost, :set_material_charge


  A4_FACTOR = 0.0626514876
  A3_FACTOR = 0.124548139
  A2_FACTOR = 0.249096276
  A1_FACTOR = 0.499702226
  B0_FACTOR = 1.41585523
  B1_FACTOR = 0.706656651
  B2_FACTOR = 0.353328326
  B3_FACTOR = 0.176664163
  B4_FACTOR = 0.0878836952

  private



  def set_material_cost
    @material_cost = self.create_material_cost(
    cost_a4: @total_cost * A4_FACTOR,
    cost_a3: @total_cost * A3_FACTOR,
    cost_a2: @total_cost * A2_FACTOR,
    cost_a1: @total_cost * A1_FACTOR,
    cost_b0: @total_cost * B0_FACTOR,
    cost_b1: @total_cost * B1_FACTOR,
    cost_b2: @total_cost * B2_FACTOR,
    cost_b3: @total_cost * B3_FACTOR,
    cost_b4: @total_cost * B4_FACTOR
    )
  end



def set_material_charge
    @material_charge = self.create_material_charge(
    sell_a4: @total_cost * A4_FACTOR * @factor,
    sell_a3: @total_cost * A3_FACTOR * @factor,
    sell_a2: @total_cost * A2_FACTOR * @factor,
    sell_a1: @total_cost * A1_FACTOR * @factor,
    sell_b0: @total_cost * B0_FACTOR * @factor,
    sell_b1: @total_cost * B1_FACTOR * @factor,
    sell_b2: @total_cost * B2_FACTOR * @factor,
    sell_b3: @total_cost * B3_FACTOR * @factor,
    sell_b4: @total_cost * B4_FACTOR * @factor
    )

  end


    end

    class MaterialCost < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :material
    end

    class MaterialCharge < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :material
    end
```

Is this what the code should look like?

Comment: don't override initialize function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tsao mention, don't override `initialize`, but if have do, you must do a call to `super`.

```
# use '*args' so super can use any arguments to 'new'
def initialize(*args)
  # as first line so Rails will do it's "magic" before yours
  super

  # these have got values by Rails (in super) IF you have them
  # in the call to 'new'
  @cost_per_sqm = @cost_per_sqm.to_f
  @ink_per_sqm  = @ink_per_sqm.to_f
  # (you have forgot this as attr_accessor?)
  @factor       = @factor.to_f
  @total_cost   = @cost_per_sqm * @ink_per_sqm
end
```

But instead of mess with `initialize` I would prefer to use another method

```
# instead of overriding 'initialize'
def init_after_create
  return if @total_cost
  # these have got values by Rails (in new) IF you have them
  # in the call to 'new'
  @cost_per_sqm = @cost_per_sqm.to_f
  @ink_per_sqm  = @ink_per_sqm.to_f
  # (you have forgot this as attr_accessor?)
  @factor       = @factor.to_f
  @total_cost   = @cost_per_sqm * @ink_per_sqm
end

def set_material_cost
  init_after_create
  @material_cost = self.create_material_cost(
  cost_a4: @total_cost * A4_FACTOR,
  cost_a3: @total_cost * A3_FACTOR,
  ....
end

def set_material_charge
  init_after_create
  @material_charge = self.create_material_charge(
  sell_a4: @total_cost * A4_FACTOR * @factor,
  sell_a3: @total_cost * A3_FACTOR * @factor,
  ...
end
```

Tip, if you have a `Hash` as last argument in a method call, or in an `Array` you don't have to use `{ ... }`

```
# example method
def some_method(options)
  ...
end
some_method(xxx: 1, yyy: 2)

# example array
arr = [ 1, 2, xxx: 1, yyy: 2 ]
#=> [1, 2, {:xxx=>1, :yyy=>2}]
```

Comment: Thank you @244an. I managed to seed the db, by making those changes, keeping the attr_accessor, keeping the `after_create` `:set_material_costs`, `:set_material_charges` statement, and did away with initialize.  What is weird is `sell_a4` should give me: 4.6750 on `material_charges`, but instead gives me: 4.4577.....of course it should have been `@cost_per_sqm + @ink_per_sqm` but after making this changes the decimal points are way off...disturbing

Comment: @godhar, when I do a control on a calculator it gives me `4.45577` with the values from your question, so it seems to be correct.

Comment: you are right, that calculation is correct. However with the current syntax configuration, these values are missing from `Material` table. Those three that are required are not showing up in the database fields of `Material`? When I remove the attr_accessor, they appear, but there is no input into the subsequent tables that are relying on it. Any ideas?

Comment: @godhar, Ok, so what fields in `init_after_create` are in the db? For fields in db you must use either e.g. `self.total_cost = ...` or `self['total_cost'] = ` (if `total_cost` is in db) and remove that from `attr_accessor`. And when using them e.g. `some_thing = total_cost` or `some_thing = self['total_cost']`. It's preferable to **not** use `self[...]` - except when the attribute is in a variable.

Comment: I solved this by not setting instance variables at `attr_accessor` , taking away `after_init` and using the field variables in what seems to me an 'Un-dry' fashion. `@total_cost` becomes redundant and I make the calculation on the fly in each `self.create` method, as I know that I can access those variables from there. No instance variable declaration and a lot of repetition, maybe this is how it needs to be, what a long learning curve! But it works. Thanks for your help @244an